# can not create new android application project in eclipse but can import and run existing

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, new-project

If I import existing android project in eclipse it works. But when I try to create new android project everything up-to last screen works but on last screen even if I press finish button, the dialog remains as it is, it doesn't get dismissed. And in Background also the project gets created, with required folders or packages but all folders and packages are blank.

[image]

e.g. in screenshot I'm trying to create project named Test, when I click finish, it gets created in background(in red).

Also there is another one project named Hi in background(in red) with empty folders and packages.

I'm using Helios(eclipse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a lot of trouble getting the SDK to work properly in Helios over the past year or so, and eventually had to upgrade.

I would either download a newer version of eclipse, or just go to the android sdk download page and download their bundle of the SDK+eclipse.